# get the duplicated select

Tags: html, jquery

I have repeated select, like below:

```
 <select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
```

in jquery I need to if user has select type="car" twice, any ideas?

Comment: What did you try in javascript/jquery ?

Comment: _"in jquery I need to if user has select type="car" twice"_ you need to... what? I'm afraid that a verb is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may combine the change event with the [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

In order to disallow to select a value already selected you may use an additional data parameter for each select.

```js
$('.select-list').on('change', function(e) {
    var sel = this.value;
    if ($('.select-list').filter((i,e) => e.value == sel).length > 1) {
        $(this).val(this.dataset.oldSelected);
        console.log("you cannot select twice...");
    } else {
        this.dataset.oldSelected = sel;
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car" selected>one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus" selected>two</option>
    <option data-type="truck">three</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list">
    <option data-type="car">one</option>
    <option data-type="bus">two</option>
    <option data-type="truck" selected>three</option>
</select>
```